# What is window criteria?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-flink, data-analysis, apache-storm

Apache Spark is time based window criteria and Flink is record based window criteria.

Any body can explain in detail what is window criteria?

Answer (score 1):

By criteria they mean a predicate or a condition. For instance, trigger a window every 2 minutes. The point of Flink is that Flink is a record based stream engine. It processes each record at a time. While Spark has micro-batches and it process all events in the time frame of the micro-batch.
Flink has the concepts of tumbling, sliding, session, and global window.

Below there is a short explanation from the link (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#window-assigners). But you can find the detail explanation with figures on the link.

> A tumbling windows assigner assigns each element to a window of a specified window size.
> The sliding windows assigner assigns elements to windows of fixed length.
> The session windows assigner groups elements by sessions of activity.
> A global windows assigner assigns all elements with the same key to the same single global window.